# Resizing Canvas by adding space on top and left..?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is it possible to resize **canvas** by adding a fresh space on top and left of the canvas - by adding `dx` pixels on left and `dy` pixels on top? If so, what is the best optimized solution to do that, if the current canvas is very large...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible with an in-memory canvas. All you have to do is "save" the canvas bitmap by drawing it to a temporary in-memory canvas, resize your canvas, and draw back the old bitmap in the right place.

Here's a live example of that:

http://jsfiddle.net/simonsarris/YdtEd/

Comment: Why then to not do that with `getImageData` and `putImageData` within same canvas? Wouldn't be that better/faster..? My canvas is huge - over 10k*10k

Comment: `ImageData` is actually extremely slow compared to using `drawImage`! Keeping it as a bitmap with `drawImage` should be about ~35 times faster.